# Can a thread pool run on a single thread function?

Tags: c, pthreads

Is it possible for a thread pool to run on a single thread function without a mutex lock?

Something like the following.

```
void* thread_func( void* p ) {
}

for( int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ ) }
    pthread_create( &t_id, &attr, thread_func, null );
}
```

Or should I pass each `pthread_create` it's own thread function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly mean, but if you intend to run the same function on all threads in your pool, it depends on whether you are accessing a shared resource e. g. a counter or similar.

Comment: @marcusshep Please don't use code formatting on random phrases, only on code and variable/function names.

Comment: You can use the same thread function for more than one thread. If you are accessing shared data which is being modified then you probably need a mutex.

Comment: @interjay great response !

Comment: It is in fact *common* to run the same thread function concurrently in multiple threads, but that's unrelated to whether you need a mutex or other synchronization aid.  Even if there is no overlap between the functions called in various threads, you need to protect access to shared data via a mutex or similar means.

Comment: The only way I know of screwing this up is by using self-modifying code, something which, in itself, damns your soul to the ninth level of hell for all eternity.

Answer (score 2):

*Is it possible for a thread pool to run on a single thread function without a mutex lock?*

Yes, it is *possible*. But it depends on your `thread_func` function. If you are accessing a shared resource, for example a counter and you don't use a mutex, then you might experience a *race-condition*:

```
int counter; // set to 2 in main function

void* thread_func(void *p) {
    counter = counter + 1;
}
```

- Thread A reads from the counter (value: 2)
- Thread B reads from the counter (value: 2)
- Thread B increases counter (value: 3)
- Thread A increases counter (value: 3)

This happens because thread A still has the value of 2 for the counter and adds 1 which results in 3 (again) even though from normal understanding the counter value should have been 4 after both threads finished increasing the value.

If you add a mutex, the threads have to wait for another thread which currently modifies the counter value.